# Not able to disable the second button or any other button when clicking on

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello can any one help me i m not able to hide the second or any other button in while loop whenever the value of textbox  is less then 5 then the button of btn_cart should be disable bt it is not happening i m able to disable only the first button in while loop if i change the value of any other textbox to less then 5 bt my first button is getting disable not the others.please help me i m stuck

```
function toggle(element) {

    if (element.value>'5') {
         document.getElementById('btn_cart').style.visibility='visible';

    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('btn_cart').style.visibility='hidden';
        alert('Please have Minimum 5 Quantity ')
    }
}



<?php   include ('dbconnect.php');
    $prodetails = mysql_query("Select * from product where category_id='$product_id' ORDER BY product_craetedate DESC ");
    while ($fetchprodata = mysql_fetch_array($prodetails))
        {
?>
<input type="number" class="item_quantity" value="5" id=""  onChange="toggle(this)"  />
<?php echo "<input type='button' class='item_add items' name='btn_cart' id='btn_cart'  value='ADD'>" ?>

<?php   } ?>
```

Comment: provide enough detail

Comment: change `element.value>'5'` to `element.value>5`

Comment: hi my javascript  is working my <input type="button" class='item_add items' name='btn_cart' id='btn_cart'/> i want to disable it whenever the value  of <input type="number" class="item_quantity" value="5" id=""  onChange="toggle(this)"  /> is less then 5 the button should be disable bt it it is going through while loop so only th first button is getting disable nt the other button is getting disable becoz it is in while loop so please check n help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given same id to every `<input type="button".......>` 
so when you do  `document.getElementById('btn_cart').style.visibility='visible';` 
 it will hide only first button.

```
<?php   include ('dbconnect.php');
$prodetails = mysql_query("Select * from product where category_id='$product_id' ORDER BY product_craetedate DESC ");
$i = 1
while ($fetchprodata = mysql_fetch_array($prodetails))
    {

?>
 <input type="number" class="item_quantity" value="5" id="<?php echo $i?>"     onChange="toggle(this)"  />
 <?php echo "<input type='button' class='item_add items' name='btn_cart' id='btn_cart".$i."'  value='ADD'>" ?>

<?php  
$i++;
} ?>
```

change in script

```
function toggle(element) {

if (element.value<'5') {
     document.getElementById('btn_cart'+element.id).style.visibility='hidden';
    alert('Please have Minimum 5 Quantity ')

   }    
}
```

Comment: @Javed siddique It answer is correct than you can accept answer and upvote it .

Answer (score 0):

Change element.value > '5' to element.value > 5

Comment: see my code my javascript is the problem  is  i want to disable the button btn_cart when the the value of <input type="number"> is less then 5.. the main issue is  the while loop it create the btn as per the fetch data bt when i m making the value less then 5 of anyother textbox the btn_Cart which is first goes disable nt the other one.